# Starting the jmeter stress test from the command line failed

Tags: jmeter

In Windows environment, jmeter is used to stress test the local springboot web project. The command line input is:

**D:\software\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin>jmeter -n -t D:\software\apache-jmeter-5.5\test\test1.jmx -l D:\software\apache-jmeter-5.5\test\result.txt -e -o D:\software\apache-jmeter-5.5\test**

The execution result is：

**Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Unrecognized option: --add-opens
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
errorlevel=1**

Java version is 1.8.0_102. Jmeter version is 5.5. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [jmeter.bat](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter.bat) file for some reason isn't able to properly detect your Java version and thinks that you're running Java 9+

If you didn't change jmeter.bat file you can raise an issue in [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) however I don't think it will be paid any attention as Java 8 is not supported anymore.

The options are in:

1. Check your local jmeter.bat file against the above version from JMeter Github. Eventually [reinstall JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)
2. Upgrade to [Java 9](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk9/) or later
3. If you cannot make any changes to the machine (upgrade Java or reinstall JMeter) you can amend your command to [run JMeter .jar file directly](https://www.baeldung.com/java-run-jar-with-arguments) without jmeter.bat wrapper script

   ```
   java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t D:\software\apache-jmeter-5.5\test\test1.jmx -l D:\software\apache-jmeter-5.5\test\result.txt -e -o D:\software\apache-jmeter-5.5\test
   ```

Comment: But I can normally start jmeter with jmeter.bat.@Dmitri T

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem by commenting out the statement in the `jmeter.bat` file:

```
set JAVA9_OPTS=--add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED ... --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED
```